# List all Items from User by its foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I am using ActiveAdmin and i want to list items which belong to a specific user.  The two resources have the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship.

An `index` pages is  listing all the users. Now i would like to render a `show block` for each user his items.
My `show` looks now something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
show do 
   panel "Specific Item List" do
       table_for Item.where("user_id=1").fnidi_each do |i|
         column("ID"){|item|item.id}
         column("Name"){|item|item.name} 
       end 
   end
end
end
```

How do i *inherit* the `user_id` from the page to the show panel ? So that each time `show` is called i can use the users id for the query.

I know these a basic question  but my knowledge of Rails/AA is so far quite basic as well ;) Happy for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code from the [ActiveAdmin documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/6-show-pages.md), where "post" seems to be dynamically generated within the register block suggests that in your case you may be able to just do "user.id", etc.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  show do
    h3 post.title
    div do
      simple_format post.body
    end
  end
end
```

So you might try user.items or Item.where(user_id: user.id) instead of your Item.where("user_id=1").